# C++ code of thinning algorithm (EVG-thin)

Tags: c++, algorithm, makefile, voronoi

I'm trying to use this [program](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/qr/software/evg-thin.html) which implements an extension of the pixel-based "thinning" algorithm that finds skeletons of bitmaps.

It's been told in Readme file that I should do a 'make' command and then the './test -image-file test1.pgm' , but I receive a set of the errors on the 'make' stage. I guess that there's something wrong with the ImageHelper.hh file, but I don't understand what exactly. Could anyone help me with this?

The [sourcecode is here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/qr/software/evg-thin.tgz)

Comment: Please show the errors you have. It is hard to help without them. You might also want to specify what compiler you are using.

Comment: As @TheDark said, your question is about impossible to answer with the information you've provided. It's buggy code. There's a datatype `uint` that's never defined.  If I replace that with `unsigned`, it compiles fine on my Macbook and runs the tests.

Comment: Hi! Thank you. Here is a link to the file containing the errors https://github.com/asarsembayev/EVG-THIN-v1.1/blob/master/errors_in_evg-thin.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to add following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

To test.cc and ImageHelper.cc